# Python Pandas Dataframe- Setting the Index as datetime with custom months

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a simple dataframe that looks like this.

```
0       0.00
1       0.00
2       0.07
3       0.09
4       0.09
...
180    13.46
181    13.46
182    15.05
183    15.05
184    15.05
185    15.05
```

I want to change the numeric index to month-dates but not in chronologic order. I want it to be Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,Nov,Dec. How could I make the index into these custom months so it skips the months I do not want?

Comment: for which years?

Comment: Waht is expected output?

Comment: Just for a single year. Expected output would have the Month-date in the index column, then the same data in second column as example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe need:

```
np.random.seed(2018)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.rand(186)})
#print (df)

#365 days
dates = pd.date_range('01-01-2015', '31-12-2015')
dates = dates[dates.month.isin([1,2,3,4,11,12])].strftime('%b-%d')
print (len(dates))
181

#366 days
dates = pd.date_range('01-01-2000', '31-12-2000')
dates = dates[dates.month.isin([1,2,3,4,11,12])].strftime('%b-%d')
print (len(dates))
182
```

And then:

```
#filter DaatFrame for same length
df = df.iloc[:len(dates)]
#assign dates
df.index = dates
print (df.head(10))
               A
Jan-01  0.882349
Jan-02  0.104328
Jan-03  0.907009
Jan-04  0.306399
Jan-05  0.446409
Jan-06  0.589985
Jan-07  0.837111
Jan-08  0.697801
Jan-09  0.802803
Jan-10  0.107215
```

Comment: I need the result to be month-date. So the first column (index) would look like: Jan-1, Jan-2, Jan-3.... down to Dec-29, Dec-30, Dec-31.

Comment: There is problem values is `181` and length of df is 186